# Is accessing global variable using macro advisable?

Tags: c

I saw this piece of code in a C file:

Abcd.h file -

```
#define X (&y)
```

Abcd.c file -

```
extern int y;
```

Is it a common practice to use macro to access global variable address or field of global structure?

Is it advisable to do so? If yes, why? If no, why?

Comment: That's just to little context to help you. How, when and where is the macro used? If it's a good idea or not depends very much on that. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Using global variables are bad practice in the first place. Inventing personal macro languages even more so.

Comment: "*is it preferable to do this?*" - Compared to what alternatives?

Comment: Edited the question to increase clarity.

Comment: in general, hiding a pointer by making it read as a normal variable is a VERY bad idea.  The code would be much clearer if (when wanting the address of 'y') the code always says '&y'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that bad...

Some implementation do something similar with `errno`:

```c
extern int *__geterrno(void);

#define errno (*__geterrno())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen macros used to simplify complex expressions, or to simplify accessing members of deeply nested structures, something like

```
#define GET_NAME(foo) (foo)->bar->blah->name
```

I've never seen anyone use a macro to *just* abstract away a `&` operation on a specific global object, though.  Without more context I can't say whether it's a good or bad idea.